# android versions and parse error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk

I built an apk using `Android 4.4.2` platform using `intelliJ 13` ,
 specified the `minSdkVersion` to 8 (`Android 2.2`). I tried to deploy the apk to a smartphone with android 4.1, but it could not be installed and gave me parse error .So, I wonder do I need to use android 4.1 api to built the apk in order to deploy it to a android 4.1 phone?

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.HelloDroid"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Something unsupported in the manifest - please include it in the question.

Comment: @laalto I have added the manifest file.

Comment: Looks simple enough. Try adding `targetSdkVersion` to `uses-sdk` as well - some devices are picky about it not being defined or defined as smaller than minimum (which will be 1 in case it is omitted)

Comment: @laalto you are correct, it is working after adding `targetSdkVersion` to `uses-sdk`

Comment: Ok, turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `targetSdkVersion` in `uses-sdk`. When it is not specified, it will default to 1. Some devices are picky if `targetSdkVersion` is smaller than `minSdkVersion` and report a parse error when processing the manifest binary XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think error is in below line

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"//Error is here.
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You need to put a "." before your activity name. Just change it to

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
```

You can see the explanation here in [Android Developer Documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm) for the tag `android:name` under `<activity />`.